# bash alias with parameters

Tags: bash, bashrc, alias

I would like to swap from csh to bash, then I have to set the .bashrc with the commands I use.
Translating alias with parameters seems to be not easier as I believed.
csh:

```
alias gr 'xmgrace -legend load -nxy \!* -free -noask&'
```

the param `\!*` means all params on the command line; Then I tried for bash:

```
alias gr='xmgrace -legend load -nxy $@ -free -noask&'
alias gr='xmgrace -legend load -nxy $(@) -free -noask&'
```

But neither worked.

The other issue comes from memorizing the current directory
csh:

```
alias t 'set t=\`pwd\``;echo $t'
alias tt 'cd $t'
```

I tried a lot of things but without any results.

Comment: `alias` cannot use parameters. for this you need to write a function.

Comment: @muru I was looking for a suitable dupe but couldn't find one..the answer from the one you have referred to does not provide the whole scenario IMHO..

Comment: @heemayl and your answer does?

Comment: @muru well, i have tried to make it more clarified....if you don't feel the same its allright..i thought i should tell you what i felt prior to answering, nothing more :)

Answer (score 5):

This is not the way `bash` aliases work, all the positional parameters in the `bash` aliases are appended at the end of the command rather than the place you have defined. To get over it you need to use `bash` functions.

An example will make you more clear :

```bsh
$ cat file.txt 
foo
$ cat bar.txt 
foobar
spamegg
$ grep -f file.txt bar.txt 
foobar

$ alias foo='grep -f "$1" bar.txt'  ## Alias 'foo'
$ foo file.txt 
grep: : No such file or directory

$ spam () { grep -f "$1" bar.txt ;}  ## Function 'spam'
$ spam file.txt 
foobar
```

As you can see as the first argument in case of alias `foo` is being added at the end so the command `foo file.txt` is being expanded to :

```
grep -f "" bar.txt file.txt
```

while in case of function `spam` the command is correctly being expanded to :

```
grep -f file.txt bar.txt
```

So in your case, you can define a function like :

```
gr () { xmgrace -legend load -nxy "$@" -free -noask & ;}
```

Comment: Can the function be saved to a `.bashrc` file?  If so, can it be aliased from the `.bashrc` file?

Comment: @alex Yes, the function can be saved in `~/.bashrc`. Not sure what you meant in your second question.

Comment: I meant something like "can that function use alias to be invoked on the shell", like `alias validate_foo=validate_bar();` (turns out the answer is no, it doesn't have to leverage `alias` as a prerequisite of being invoked on the shell). Thanks!